# SSIS Package not showing under MSDB file

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 and after trial and error I created a package the server agent executes on a schedule, on test server. When I move over to the production server - Using SSMS logged in as SA -  I create the package from right clicking the database and going to tasks just like I did in test.

When I log into the Integration Services I see all the folders including the `MSDB` folder, but my saved package isn't there. When I go to Server agent and navigate to the package I created it's there! But it fails when the Server Agent runs it.

I am trying to eliminate the running of the package itself as the thing causing the error. This is the first time anyone has used the Integration service on the production server so maybe there's a setup step that was missed? How do I get my packages to show up in SSMS under the MSDB folder just like on my test database?

Comment: On production, did you install it to MSDB or the file system? There are two ways to "install" a pacakge. The MSDB option "installs" it within the database. The file system option points SQL Server to package on the file system.

Comment: Check all the folders under "Stored Packages" and see if it's in a different folder other than MSDB.

Comment: I've check all the folders and sub folders, not there. I've been saving the file as SQLserver. I will try file system and see if that helps. I am also thinking the server wasn't rebooted after install of SSIS so maybe that will help if I reboot tonight after hours.

Comment: Is this a multi-instanced box? If you run the first query from [SSIS Package Query](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/08/ssis-package-query.html) on production, do you see the missing package?